# configuring AWS Network Load Balancer for logstash cluster Running in ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-elb

- My Aim is to setup A common logstashcluster that scales, as I am
  using filebeat in my backup servers for collection of logs .
- For that    I setup an ELB that points out to the Logstash cluster
  (Auto scaling    group)
- In ELB target group settings i gave the health check port as 9600, as my logstash is running at 9600 port.
- But when The ELB runs the healthcheck it says always  unhealthy instance
  [image]

- I am not sure what i am doing wrong here
- My logstash config

```
input {
 beats {
   type => "testlog"
   port => "5066"
 }
}
filter {
   if [message] =~ /{.*}/ {
       grok { match => { "message" => "(?<[@metadata][json]>({.*}))"} }
       json { source => "[@metadata][json]" remove_field => [ "message" ] }
   }
}

output {
 stdout {
       codec => rubydebug
       }
 amazon_es {
   hosts => ["****************************"]
   region => "us-east-1"
   index => "filebeatsecondpipelinefinal1-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
   #user => "elastic"
   #password => "changeme"
 }
}
```

- Im having multiple pipeline setup so another config uses this

```
input {
  beats {
    type => "testlog"
    port => "5044"
  }
}
filter {
    if [message] =~ /{.*}/ {
        grok { match => { "message" => "(?<[@metadata][json]>({.*}))"} }
        json { source => "[@metadata][json]" remove_field => [ "message" ] }
    }
}

output {
  stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
        }
  amazon_es {
    hosts => ["************************"]
    region => "us-east-1"
    index => "filebeatsecondpipelinefinal2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you set `http.host` to the local ip of your instance? By default `http.host` uses `127.0.0.1` so you will only by able to make a request to the port `9600` from the local machine, not from outside.

Comment: Also, the port that your logstash listens for inputs from your beats is not the same port that it will anser to healthchecks. The `9600` port is by default the API port, it is not used to send logs to logstash. What is your logstash configuration? Which ports are you using for your pipeline and for the API?

Comment: Hi leandrojmp 
Pls see my post i have updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your ELB and Logstash configuration.

First, the port `9600` is the REST port to get logstash metrics, which you can use to do healthcecks, but by default and per security reasons, logstash binds this port to the loopback ip (127.0.0.1), you will need to add the `http.host` config in your `logstash.yml` to bind it to the internal IP of the intance.

```
http.host: "instance-local-ip"
```

You need to do that in every logstash host, you can also use environment variables in the logstash [config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html).

Second, your ELB target group is using the wrong port. Your pipelines are using the ports `5044` and `5066`, so you will need a target group for port `5044` and another one for port `5066`, and when configuring the healthcheck for those target group you will need to chose the override port option and use the port `9600`.

This way your target group will listen on the port `5044` or `5066` but will perform the healthcheck for your instances on port `9600`.